# Dynamically allocated 3d array with unknown parameters

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, file-handling

My task is to get an input from a file. The input looks like the example down below. In order to work with it I have to store the unknown quantity of rows and I have to be able to get to them one by one, as well as store the unknown amount of words in each row so I can access them later on.

Example of input:

```
U a b c x y z
S a b c x
S x y z
S x
S a b c
```

My first thought was to create a 3-dimensional array, where it would look like this: `char arr[number of rows][number of words][maximum length of a word = 30]` That way I would be able to access them quite easily.

The problem that I got stuck with is that I have to allocate it dynamically, and as I said, the number of rows and the number of words in each row varies with each input file.

I am not sure how to dynamically allocate this. Maybe some different approach would be more efficient. This is just what I have came up with.

Comment: Avoid adding images Also sort Question properly.

Comment: If the amount of items per row varies then a 3D array isn't very suitable since it takes up lots of extra memory. It would seem that you should rather create a system with structs containing pointer arrays and sizes.

Answer (score 1):

The implementation will be much easier if you have some limit on the number of words per row.

For instance,

```
#define MAX_WORDS_PER_ROW 50 
#define MAX_CHARS_PER_WORD 30 //provided in question
```

You can have a struct that represents one row, namely

```
typedef struct row {

char[MAX_WORDS_PER_ROW][MAX_CHARS_PER_WORD] words;
int num_words;

} row;
```

You can then count the number of rows in each file

```
int num_rows = 0;
char line[1024];
while(fgets(line,sizeof(line),file)){
    num_rows++;
}
```

Finally, you can create an array sized exactly to the number of rows

```
row* rows = malloc(sizeof(row)*num_rows);
```

Afterward, you can parse the file line by line and populate the `rows` array. You may need to use `fseek` to move the file pointer back to the start. Don't forget to free the `rows` array before exiting.

If you do not have any upper limit on the number of words per row, this may require nested dynamic memory allocations, which can be a real headache and lead to memory leaks.